HTTP Error 403: Forbidden when import library fetch_california_housing to google collab
I got error  HTTP Error 403: Forbidden when import fetch_california_housing to google collab. Here s my code:
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

housing = fetch_california_housing()

Frequency of the bug is : sometimes. Last time i ve seen error s yesterday, today it doesn't happen anymore.
Temporary repair solution ? Ignore it by:
import warnings # import to ignore HTTP 403 error fetch_california_housing
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") # import to ignore HTTP 403 error fetch_california_housing

here s my full code:
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
import warnings # import to ignore HTTP 403 error fetch_california_housing
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") # import to ignore HTTP 403 error fetch_california_housing

housing =fetch_california_housing()


Got the same error HTTP error 403: Forbidden
